# What is the group cohomology set $H^1(\mathbb{Z},GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p^{ur}))$?

Tags: group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

As in title, what is the group cohomology set $H^1(\mathbb{Z},GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p^{ur}))$ ?

Here the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p^{ur})$ is via Galois action: consider $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\cong Gal(\mathbb{Q}_p^{ur}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$.

Does anyone computed this before or give me a hint?

Comment: Do you know the equivalent with $\mathbb{Z}_p^{ur}$ replaced with $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$? It’s (more or less) called *Lang’s theorem*.

Comment: I don't. I have computed the cohomology group in the case of $GL_1$, the answer seems to be $\mathbb{Q}_p$.